# Загрузка c# приложения на хостинг

Tags: c#, хостинг, telegram-bot

Хочу создать telegram bot .cs и сразу возник вопрос, куда загружать и как осуществить "вечную" исполняемость. Рыская в сети создалось впечатление, что нужен хостинг с asp.net, ещё и vps для запуска приложения (правильно ли понял, что vps для длительного исполнения, а остальные для загрузки файлов и исполнения скриптов с ограничением по времени?)
Ps.
Могу путаться в терминах, ибо до этого занимался только олимпиадной прогой и ничего полезного не создал. Подумал, тема с ботами - отличное начало.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET приложения имеют ограниченный жизненный цикл(пулл IIS по умолчанию 20мин). Т.е. сохранить состояние приложения можно только на 20 мин(вам это не подходит). Вам достаточно будет только VPS и запустить не нем банальное консольное приложение(жизненный цикл которой может быть не ограничен), которое и будет делать ваши web-request-ы =)

Comment: Денис, я правильно понимаю, что для запуска приложения, мне понадобится среда .net framework ?

Comment: @mordi, если ты конечно пишешь на C#.NET. Можно запустить любое приложение (как дома на ноутбуке), лишь бы на сервере ты поставил все нужные компоненты для запуска своего приложения.

Comment: При чём тут жизненный цикл? 20 минут - это же время сессии. Время до выгрузки приложения из памяти определяется настройками iis'a и может зависеть от хостинга. Вероятно, у платных хостингов этой проблемы нет. А состояние можно и даже нужно замечательно хранить в БД. Vps тут вообще не при чём.

Comment: @mordi, естественно для запуска C# кода нужен .net framework (в случае windows-хостинга) и, вероятно, mono в случае линукс-хостинга. Но я бы не стал связываться с линуксом, если только ты не пишешь на новом .net core.

Comment: @Qwertiy если у хостинга нет ограничения по времени жизни пула - значит, либо это VDS-ка, либо такое ограничение быстро появится :)

Answer (score 3):

Ничего не знаю про ботов, так что ответ приблизительный.

Asp.net хостинг позволяет запускать код на C# - это очевидно. Однако, далеко не любой хостинг позволяет запускать демонов. Если бот просто даёт ответ на запрос - то это годится, если же он должен сам непрерывно работать, что-то делать и самостоятельно просыпаться, то нет. Что касается постоянного хранения данных, для этого можно использовать любую БД - как правило, хостинги её предоставляют.

Также следует обратить внимание на правила хостинга в отношении потребления ресурсов, особенно, если он бесплатный. Например, там может быть прописано, что твоё приложение обязано спать минимум 6 часов в сутки.

VPS - это виртуальный сервер, на котором ты можешь делать что угодно. В общем-то удобно. Бесплатных с момента закрытия nodeninja мне найти не удалось.

Из бесплатных asp.net-хостингов знаю только [appharbor](//appharbor.com/pricing), но сам никогда не пользовался.

Ещё можно развернуть приложение где-то у себя и использовать сервис динамических dns.

Comment: после размещения на хостинге (asp.net) запуск производится через консоль хостинг-провайдера или это производится другим способом?

Comment: @mordi, к сожалению, не знаю. Возможно, зависит от хостинга. Возможно, он сам разместит приложение и будет ждать http-обращения на указанный порт.

Comment: то есть возможно сделать запрос путём простого просто вбивания url в браузере аля http://путь/файл.exe ? Поправь если я не прав, но насколько мне известно хостинг позволяет исполнять только скрипты. И как произвести завершение приложения в таком случае?

Comment: @mordi, нет. exe нельзя. Но ведь код на шарпе можно и на asp.net-странице использовать.

Comment: Попробовал сегодня на appharbor тестовый сайт залить. Ну, бесплатность действительно присутствует, но лимиты бесплатного очень жёсткие (20 мегабайт под БД MS SQL), но сервис весьма качество сделан. Единственный упоминание appharbor на ru so, поэтому не удержался отписать впечатления.

Comment: @AK, спасибо! Учту, если понадобится. Вообще для базы можно что-то другое использовать ведь? А вообще, сейчас должны хостинги под .net core появляться - можно их ещё потыкать.

Answer (score 3):

Для хостинга консольного бота

- на **.Net** подойдёт любая **windows-машина**
- для бота на **.Net Core** подойдёт вообще любая

Главное - наличие выхода в интернет. Такой вариант хостинга лучше всего подходит для получения обновлений с помощью метода **getUpdates**. Однако, **вебхуки** тоже можно получать, хостясь на **Mac, Windows, Linux, FreeBSD** и без особых сложностей. Это можно осуществить с помощью [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) - он выдаст https-адрес и будет перенаправлять пакеты.

[Пример](http://frontender.info/expose-yourself-with-ngrok/#primerizrealynogomira) работы с **вебхуками** через **Ngrok**.

> Building webhook integrations can be a pain: it requires a public address and a lot of set up to trigger hooks. Save yourself time and frustration with ngrok. Inspect the HTTP traffic flowing over your tunnel. Then, replay webhook requests with one click to iterate quickly while staying in context.

---

*Спасибо @PashaPash за конструктивные замечания к ответу.*

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/100740)

Comment: @denis, не соглашусь.

Comment: @Anatol боты телергама вроде бы используют входящие вебхуки - их *неудобно* принимать в консольном приложении.

Comment: @Pasha, не обязательно использовать вебхуки. There are two mutually exclusive ways of receiving updates for your bot — the getUpdates method on one hand and Webhooks on the other. Incoming updates are stored on the server until the bot receives them either way, but they will not be kept longer than 24 hours. Regardless of which option you choose, you will receive JSON-serialized Update objects as a result.

Comment: @Pasha, а в чём, собственно, неудобство?

Comment: @Anatol в том, что сайты обрабатывают вопросы намного лучше и удобнее. замечание про getUpdates стоит вставить в сам ответ :)

Comment: @Anatol ничего не препятствует, как и хостингу сайта в консольном приложении. но, по какой-то странной причине, люди предпочитают хостить сайты под iis. Т.к. asp.net приложение гораздо легче справляется с задачей "сидеть на 80-ом порту и ждать http-запроса - вебхука", чем консольное.