# тестирование бота для telegram на локальной машине

Tags: тестирование, telegram-bot

Как тестировать бота для telegram на локальной машине? У меня есть бот, который получает сообщения через webhook. Бот написан на python и сохранен на серверах google app engine. Я использую фреймворк flask. Сейчас я корректирую код бота локально, затем загружаю его на сервер и таким образом тестирую. Может быть есть возможность протестировать бота локально, до загрузки на сервер? Если запустить скрипт бота на исполнение на локальной машине, а потом в строке браузера указать url с хуком что вроде http://127.0.0.1:8080/HOOK, то сообщения не приходят. Подскажите как тестировать на локальной машине?

Comment: Попробуй прокинуть свой локальный адрес в интернет, с помощью этой утилиты: https://ngrok.com (ngrok creates a secure public URL (https://yourapp.ngrok.io) to a local webserver on your machine)

Comment: попробуйте ngrok, писал об этом тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552141/183842

Answer (score 0):

чем не угодил pyCharm? Есть community версия (бесплатная).
запускаете код на локальной машине, и тестируете.
у Вас ведь в коде прописан URL для вебхуков?